# dynamically built checkboxes are being reset on scroll

Tags: java, android, realm, android-adapter

I have a list view with adaptor where I create some checkboxes, in the adaptor I add an on change listener to change the value in my realm database. Just above this I am getting the current values stored in the database to persist the previous values.

This seems to work rather well, but when you scroll the items that you have checked will become unchecked when past the screen.

As seen here:

[image]
[image]

The code that generates this:

Adaptor.java

```
if(check != null){
    viewHolder.checkbox.setText(check.title);

    if (check.completed == 1) {
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

    viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                check.setCompleted();
            } else {
                check.setNotCompleted();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Fragment.java

```
final ChecksAdaptor checksAdaptor = new ChecksAdaptor(device.checks(), getContext());

listView.setAdapter(checksAdaptor);
```

Full Adaptor

```
public class ChecksAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<DeviceCheck> {

    public RealmResults<DeviceCheck> checks;

    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    public ChecksAdaptor(RealmResults<DeviceCheck> checks, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.check_row_item, checks);
        this.checks = checks;
        this.mContext=context;
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        final DeviceCheck check = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }

        lastPosition = position;

        if(check != null){
            viewHolder.checkbox.setText(check.title);

            if (check.completed == 1) {
                viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
            }

            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        check.setCompleted();
                    } else {
                        check.setNotCompleted();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `check`?

Comment: Thats the item from the list of checks that gets passed into the adapter

Comment: That object needs to be part of the ViewHolder. Please show the full Adapter code

Comment: See above whole adaptor in there

Comment: Can you try adding `new ViewHolder(check);`? Then using that to update the row view? For example, `viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(viewHolder.check.completed == 1);`

Comment: Sorry where would that go?

Comment: Right after `if(check != null){`  insert `viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)`

Comment: Perfect works a treat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [mTak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8959091/mtak)

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
```